# Do I need to turn the rewrite engine on more than once?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silex

I want to start using Silex on Apache and according to [silex docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) I need to insert this code into my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However I already have this code above it, which works fine:

```
# www.foo.com will point to foo.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/foo\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Can I omit `RewriteEngine` on?

Furthermore b.c. rewriting already has been verified to work can I remove the `IfModule` statement?

They don't explain what the code does in their docs so any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the `<IfModule>` is [mostly pointless/detrimental](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108#~begone). And no, a single `RewriteEngine On` does per .htaccess file.